# Improve the speed of reading and persisting Apache POI excel file

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jpa, apache-poi

I have an Excel file that I am currently able to import into a mySQL database, but I would like to increase the speed of the import somewhat. My set up for reading the Excel files (approx 40,000 rows in each file, 10-15 columns) and persisting is as follows:

*** Java Code ***

```
public void importFileToDataBase(String file) {
        try {
            FileInputStream latestExcelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        Sheet bigSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= bigSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

            try {

                row = bigSheet.getRow(i);
                String bigSheetId = i + "";
                Date column1 = row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue();
                int column2 = (int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
                int column3 = (int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
                int column4 = (int) row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
                int column5 = (int) row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue();
                int column6 = (int) row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue();
                int column7 = (int) row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue();
                String column8 = row.getCell(9).toString();
                String column9 = row.getCell(11).toString();
                String column10 = row.getCell(12).toString();
                String column11 = row.getCell(13).toString();
                int column12 = (int) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue();
                Double column13 = row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue();
                String column14 = row.getCell(2)
                        .toString();

                BigSheet mySheet = new BigSheet(
                        baseDataTableId, column1, column2, column3, column4,
                        column5, column6, column7, column8, column9,
                        column10, column11, column12, column13, column14);

                putInDatabase(mySheet);
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
```

Is there a way to improve the speed of the import via batching?

If so, could you give an example of how to do this (if it's possible)?

Comment: Which db are you using? Batch update will improve performance in most cases. Sometimes, dependant on the db, committing every e.g. 500 rowss speeds things up too.

Comment: Using a mySql Database - persisting via JPA - its running ok at the moment but i just need to get it faster

Comment: You have to find out the part which is consuming the most time first. If you have identified the part, e.g. using a profiler, you can work on improving it.

Comment: Why not export the spreadsheet into CSV format, and then write a simple MySQL import script?

Comment: Hi data nucleus, I would rather use the java method at present, if I fail to speed it up then I'll look at scripting, cheers

Comment: It's likely the performance has nothing to do with reading the spreadsheet, but comes from the inserts that you have not shown (i.e. the method putInDatabase()). Comment that out ans see if it runs faster. As Timo said, SQL updates can usually be batched, giving huge speed improvements.

Comment: Cheers, i have actually got this working with SQL inserts aswell and is about twice as quick - but im aiming to use JPA as the method to insert (client preference..). The put in database is essentially entityManager.persist(rowOfData); and happens at the end of each loop which is a slow point im guessing.

Comment: try to add in balk and not every row